# Why results are different from call and predict in a Keras model? It seems predict ignore any random generated value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am seeing different behaviours between calling a model, and calling the `predict` method. It seems predict would ignore all randomly generated values.

In this [notebook](https://github.com/nlhkh/dropout-in-rnn/blob/random_noise/Random%20noise.ipynb) I am trying to introduce stochastic process to my network.

Basically, for every entry, I duplicate it 10 times, and for each slice, I add some random noise.

When calling the model with a tensor, I am seeing expected output, where an input entry yields some noise.
When calling `predict` on the same data, I am seeing only the same output.

So I save the model weights, and load the weights to a similar model without any noise to verify my hypothesis. Indeed, without noise, it yields the same outputs for call and predict, and the same outputs with the previous noisy model when calling `predict`.

Why am I seeing this behaviour? Does it mean that when training the network with `fit`, it will ignore random values as well?

Comment: I think probably with `predict` it is using a graph-compiled version of the model where the batch dimension is `None`, therefore taking the first path in the branch of your `foo` function. Why don't you simply do `return x + tf.random.normal(K.shape(x))`?

Comment: That's a good point. I am still new to this graph concept in TF. At first I was using K.random_normal(K.int_shape(x)), and it threw exception because some dimensions are None. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @jdehesa excellent! I needed to use K.shape instead of K.int_shape because I need symbolic dimensions. Now predict and call agree on the outputs. Your comment is as good as an answer, so you can paste the answer here if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `predict`, Keras uses a TensorFlow compiled graph to run the model which, among other things, means that the batch dimension of the data tensor will generally be `None` (because you can predict on batches of any size). In your `foo` function that adds the noise to the input:

```py
def foo(x):
    B, D = K.int_shape(x)
    if B is None:
        return x
    else:
        mask = tf.random.normal((B,D))
        return x + mask
```

You use `int_shape` to get the shape of `x` as Python integers, or `None` for unknown dimensions. This works as expected with eager tensors, where all dimensions are always known, but in graph mode the returned batch dimension `B` is `None`, so the conditional goes through the first branch and the input remains untouched.

The simplest solution is to use `shape` instead, which will give you another tensor (symbolic or eager) containing the full shape of `x`, and which you can use to generate the random noise:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + tf.random.normal(K.shape(x))
```

This should always work as expected.